# css not applying for asp.net hyperlink

Tags: html, asp.net, css, hyperlink, hover

In my `asp.net` application, there is a `hyperlink`. I want to change it's `color` to white when I hover over it using `css`, but it is not working.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlViewItem" class="hplClass" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Pro_Id","ProductDetails.aspx?ProID={0}") %>' ForeColor="#33ccff">View Item</asp:HyperLink>
```

My `css`:

```
.hplClass:hover
{
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: See [this ASP.Net question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203228/difference-between-class-vs-cssclass-in-asp-net-css-css-syntax-question) to learn more on CSSClass in `ASP.Net`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (After removing ForeColor="#33ccff")  :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlViewItem" CssClass="hplClass" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Pro_Id","ProductDetails.aspx?ProID={0}") %>'>View Item</asp:HyperLink>
```

Also make sure that you have added the reference of css file in your aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET controls use attribute `CssClass` instead of 'class'.

Comment: now i have edited my code, but still not working 
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlViewItem" CssClass="hplClass" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Pro_Id","ProductDetails.aspx?ProID={0}") %>' ForeColor="#33ccff">View Item</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: Does the rendered HTML contain `class="hplClass"`?

Comment: yes. 
after viewing source , i got this
<a id="ContentBodyPlace_dlLatestItem_hlViewItem_2" class="hplClass" href="ProductDetails.aspx?ProID=4" style="color:#33CCFF;">View Item</a>

Comment: Then you should look elsewhere. Perhaps your CSS is not getting loaded. If you put `<style>.hplClass:hover { color: white; }</style>` just before your control, that should make sure CSS is there. If that works, see why the CSS is not loading from where you had it before.