# Trying to change the color of my validation control using a style sheet theme

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I created a style sheet theme named Basic. And Applied it to my web.config file. Then I created a class in the css file called Validator. I used cssClass attribute with the Validator type. The font-width is working but for some reason I can't get the color to change, it's stuck at red. I know the style sheet theme is working and the control because the font-width property corresponds when i makes changes, but the color text property isn't working.

Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages styleSheetTheme="Basic" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

ASPX Code:

```
<p id="validation"> 
    &nbsp;<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
        CssClass="validator"  HeaderText="Please correct the following 
        errors:" />
</p>
```

Basic.css Code:

```
.validator{
color: Gray !important;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Revised: Added code now works correctly and changes color to Gray.

Comment: Try adding `!important` to `color` like `color:Gray !important`

Comment: I changed it to color:Gray, i don't think it's a syntax problem because my debugger didn't flag anything.

Comment: Did you add `!important` property to your `color:Gray` as I've shown?

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to use class attribute instead of CssClass
<p id="validation"> 
    &nbsp;<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
        class="validator"  HeaderText="Please correct the following 
        errors:" />
</p>
```

not sure if in asp it is used as CssClass since i never used ASP

Comment: `CssClass` is valid here. It will automatically render it up in `html` to `class`. You can see justification **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1203242/2065039)** and he has also said that `font-weight` is working and only `color` is not working

Comment: Yea I'm scratching my head with this one. I even Added styleSheetTheme="Basic" to my page directive, to make sure it's actually on. Could it have to do something with enableTheming?

Comment: CssClass and Class attribute both seem to call validator correctly because the font-width is working.

Comment: did you try adding !important as mentioned by guruprasad

Comment: .validator{
color: Gray !important;
font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: It's freaking werid. It work. Now it stopped working again. Could it be my internet explorer, I'm using to debug with?

Comment: use crome debugger tool and check out what is over writing the css and make changes accordingly

Comment: I used chrome to run the localhost url, and it was displaying correctly. I'm thinking this is an internet explorer problem. Explorer is up to date.

Comment: use #cccccc instead of gray for color and try